# Visual Studio Diagsession Profile Sessions - Shows Broken Function Name

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, profiling, azure-web-app-service

I downloaded a profiling session from an Azure App Service. I opened it in Visual Studio to observe why is my app taking a long time to process requests. VS doesn't show me any of my code and my fear is that it marks it as "[Broken]". Is there a way to fix this? Import my symbols (I assume) somehow?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: @joyWang .... how is this helpful.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981854 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227928 (all are unsolved)