# What does [Broken] indicate in the Function Name column of a CPU Usage report?

Tags: visual-studio, profiling

I've run Visual Studio's CPU Usage profiler on a small program, and part of the output is listed under a [Broken] entry. I get this result with a Debug build and a Release build. What does this entry indicate?

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio]

Comment: Perfview help shows details: "When a sample is taken, the ETW system attempts to take a stack trace.    For a variety of reasons it is possible that this will fail before a complete stack is taken.    PerfView uses the heuristic that all stacks should end in a frame in a particular OS DLL (ntdll) which is responsible for creating threads.   If a stack does not end there, PerfView assumes that it is broken, and injects a pseudo-node called 'BROKEN' between the thread and the part of the stack that was fetched (at the very least it will have the address of where the sample was taken)."

Comment: Visual Studio's CPU Usage profiler and Perfview use both ETW, so both may have same logic to detect such issue and mark them both as broken

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks! Can you post an answer with that info so I can award the bounty?

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the underlying issue is? The explanation is interesting, but it doesn't help with fixing this thing.

Comment: @isanae I didn't. I do have a hunch that it's related to our usage of SqlServerTypes, which depends on a native DLL. Yesterday I also saw the same thing appearing while doing an investigation of a different issue with PerfView, which confirms the answer.

Comment: I'm getting this in a pretty plain C++ project, but only with optimizations on. It's the first time I've seen this in many years of using this profiler.

Comment: @isanae Might be worth it to open a bug report on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/, if you do so please post the link here. I probably won't be investigating it any further because the particular performance issue I was looking into has been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use this tool, but a similar tool called [Perfview](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/releases/latest) that does include this hint in its help:

> When a sample is taken, the ETW system attempts to take a stack trace.
>   For a variety of reasons it is possible that this will fail before a
>   complete stack is taken.    PerfView uses the heuristic that all
>   stacks should end in a frame in a particular OS DLL (ntdll) which is
>   responsible for creating threads.   **If a stack does not end there,
>   PerfView assumes that it is broken, and injects a pseudo-node called
>   'BROKEN' between the thread and the part of the stack that was fetched**
>   (at the very least it will have the address of where the sample was
>   taken).

Both use Event Tracing for Windows (ETW), so both may use similar logic to show them as BROKEN.