# Visual Studio Profiler showing "[broken]" as function names

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, profiling

I am trying to profile my c++ dll, but the profiler is not working with me. I would like to see the call tree an so on, but only the stl functions show up, and not all disjoint - when i click on any function, their caller is "[broken]".

I don't know if my google skills are just not sufficient, but i can not find any information on what [broken] means, and how to fix it.

This is a debug build. I cannot guarantee this is not due to some compiler settings, but i fell like i have tried everything.

It should be noted that breaking the code and adding breakpoints works fine, so the profiler just doesn't access this information

If it adds any information, profiling the specific DLL as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/how-to-limit-instrumentation-to-specific-dlls?view=vs-2017) gives the exception "File contains no data buffers".

[image: Profiler output]

Comment: For future readers of this: I never managed to get it to work. I got a new PC, reinstalled everything, and now it works without any problems. Sorry for not being  more helpfull

Comment: Perhaps, profiler waits too long for something e.g. symbol server, so it is considered "broken".    In the same program, sometimes (30%) I got "broken", while other cases are OK.  It might be my `alt+tab` to internet browser window that causes trouble for profiler.

Comment: Well the code is locally on my pc, so i dont see how that could be. It doesnt take an unreasonably long time, and there is no timeout warning

Comment: I just found a related post partially explains it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227928/what-does-broken-indicate-in-the-function-name-column-of-a-cpu-usage-report

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that something wrong with PDBs of your output (for instance, you may have /DEBUG:FASTLINK set in your linker's settings, which produces reference-only PDBs).

If it's not the case, you may try [my profiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArtemGevorkyan.MicroProfilerx64x86) - it works as an extension to VisualStudio, is instrumenting (meaning it's function-accurate) and displays stats in realtime.

Comment: Since i can see that this question is indeed still being viewed be other users: Somehow your profiler is able to do what Visual Studio is not. This profiler is definatly a good option, if the problem itself cannot be resolved. Thanks!

Comment: What made you come up with the idea that reference-only PDBs are relates to [Broken]?  I am considering to remove such setting from all of my projects

Comment: @javaLover I _presume_ MSVS' profiler was using dbghelp.dll rather than [DIA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2019) that is used by the MSVC debugger. And that feature was (I need to check, though, if it still is) unsupported, as the default dbghelp.dll came with Windows before the feature first made it to MSVC 2015 (14.0). I was quite confident, because I had issues reported that my profiler wasn't showing symbols either because of the very same reason.